# How to map CALayer texture to cube so text in layer show up correctly?

Tags: scenekit

I am adding a CALayer to a SCNBox geometry contents... It works and I see this:

[image]

I want to be able to see the text on the box correctly. I understand that the texture is now applied to the geometry etc...

How can make it so the text I write in the CALayer shows up horizontally around the box...?

Answer (score 1):

the default UVs (or texture coordinates) of an `SCNBox` are such that the same content is displayed on each side. You will have to rebuild a geometry with new texture coordinates so that the pattern does not repeat. You can start from scratch, or build an `SCNBox` and retrieve its `geometrySources`.

Comment: If I pass in a UIImage it shows the image correctly on all faces. When I sue a simple CALayer I get what I get above. I am not sure how to change the texture coordinates. Any hint? thank you